# US: Using a fake name and profile photo to provide freelance services online - anything illgeal?

Tags: united-states, tax-law, business, fraud

I want to anonymously perform freelancing services online, so I used an AI generator to create a picture of a human face and chose a fake name. That fake name is also the business name on my PayPal business account. Recently, I've also launched a website that sells the freelance services under that fake name. I'm planning to deduct the costs associated with the website as business expenses when doing taxes.

Sometimes I also use that name to sign contracts with a made-up signature by me.

Will any of this be questionable to the IRS, count as potential employee fraud, or somehow counts as impersonation?

Edit: the wording of this might be confusing, but I'm NOT using any fake names or images when filing taxes or dealing with the government. It's just towards clients.

Comment: Have you filed a DBA (doing business as) also called fictitious  business name ?

Answer (score 4):

If you aren't publicly registering a trade name you are probably engaged in illegal conduct. Among other things, by doing this, you are effectively hiding yourself from any lawsuits arising from the business that accurately name the defendant.

You can have a business mascot or trade name, but you have to disclose that this is what it is and provide a means by which a reasonable person who needs to sue you could properly identify you.